# Routing Overlapping Transit Lines in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, network-analyst, route

I am trying to model a local bus network in ArcGIS 10.2 and using the Network Analyst Extension to find the shortest path. There are sections of a line in which a bus passes and then returns to form a kind of loop on the same road section before continuing on the journey. I tried to model this by copying the edges twice and giving a 0 Z-elevation on the way in and 1 Z-elevation on the way out.

Although this method has worked when i put the stops outside this "loop"  sometimes it is not working correctly (shortest time) when the stop is inside the loop, rather than stopping on the first pass, it goes all the way inside and then comes back and stops on the way out. The impedance value is set to Minutes.

Any ideas why this may be so?